# How to add red star with name of column header in Nattable?

Tags: nattable

i am trying to update the columname after doing some filter with red star.But is am not able to do it.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styling in the column header is the same as anywhere else. You typically set a label on the column header cell that should be styled differently, and then register a custom painter for that label. And if you want to show a red star with black colored text, I suppose you need to decorate a `TextPainter` with an `ImagePainter` for the red star, or use a `RichTextPainter`, as the default `TextPainter` does not support different font styles.